# How to keep the trailing zeros after decimal point

Tags: sql, types, hive

So my Alteryx output truncates trailing zeros after decimal point which makes it difficult for me to apply string operations like add "%"

So something like this:

```
Alteryx Column

38.5

23.75

27

 Current Output by adding "%"

38.5%

23.75%

27%

Desired Output

38.50%

23.75%

27.00%
```

Answer (score 1):

For these numbers, you can use:

```
format_number(col, 2) || '%'
```

or `printf()`:

```
printf('%0.2f%%', col)
```